# Get values from the Datasnapshot object with keys in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to print some data after getting from the `DataSnapShot` object. For printing it, I am doing in this way;

```
private void getUpdates(DataSnapshot DS){
    for(DataSnapshot mydata:DS.getChildren()){
     Log.i("", String.valueOf(data));
    }
}
```

and making `firebase` instance as;

```
       FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("myDB");
        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                getUpdates(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                getUpdates(dataSnapshot);
            }
```

Printing as:

```
 DataSnapshot { key = areaName, value = myName1}
    DataSnapshot { key = decs, value =  desc1}
    DataSnapshot { key = areaName, value = myName2 }
    DataSnapshot { key = desc, value = desc2 }
```

But **I want to get only `desc` values.**

My Model class is:

```
public class Singleton {
    private String areaName;
    private String desc;


    public Singleton(String areaName, String desc) {
        this.areaName = areaName;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getAreaName() {
        return areaName;
    }

    public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
        this.areaName = areaName;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }



}
```

I tried in this way;

```
String decsrip= (String) mydata.child("desc").getValue();
Log.i("", decsrip);
```

But it is printing

```
null
```

Then I tried as

```
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) mydata.getValue();
String descrip = (String) map.get("desc");
Log.i("",descrip );
```

The application crashed by saying

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Where the data is? Can I get the value of `desc` only?

Comment: First , I will need to see the Model class you have used for that data which are under `DS.getChildren()`. Put more code in question , how you are creating DatabaseReference and Your model class for the record you are reading.

Comment: @MKJParekh Question is updated. Kindly take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only thing you need to do is that

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference("myDB");
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Singleton data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Singleton.class);
        Log.i("", String.valueOf(data.getDesc()));
    }

    ...
}
```

You also need to add an empty constructor to your `Singleton` model.

```
public class Singleton {
  private String areaName;
  private String desc;

  public Singleton() {
  }

  public Singleton(String areaName, String desc) {
    this.areaName = areaName;
    this.desc = desc;
  }

  public String getAreaName() {
    return areaName;
  }

  public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
    this.areaName = areaName;
  }

  public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
  }

  public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
  }
}
```

Comment: This line `Singleton data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Singleton.class);` is giving  this error `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.example.fyp_awais.carparki_o.Singleton is missing a constructor with no arguments`

Comment: Then add empty constructor for Singleton

Comment: Empty constructor in model class??